# Android Emulator - Command Line Building

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator, terminal, building

Back again on Stack needing help from fellow Android Developers. In my development environment im using a lot of command line building and management. Currently im running into a issue where the Terminal "Using Mac OSX" when executing the command "emulator -avd nameOfemulator" the Terminal is still live.

Example of Launching Emulator

[image: Launching Emulator]

However even when the emulator is open and live, The Terminal is not let go to be able to execute additional command, I dont want to just open a new tab or window to have to execute my adb command's. Currently i can closes the emulator and kill the live terminal/emulator command by a simple 'ctrl-C' however this defeats the purpose if the emulator is closed.

Does anybody know of anyway of getting the terminal live again, either through a script, string of commands, different type of emulator's, etc.

### UPDATE

Now running the following command `emulator -avd NexusSeven &` This emulator has the HAX Intel Hardware Acceleration enabled. And shortly after the terminal becomes available again, The string "`HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode`" is inputted into the command input and makes the terminal live again.
[image: After running Command in separate thread, HAX string is inputted making terminal live again]

Comment: Just run it in background, it's linux after all: `emulator -avd NexusSeven &`

Comment: Wow! Its that easy, I guess you learn something everyday. Thanks @323go

Comment: I added it as answer, as it might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since MacOSX is just a fork of BSD Linux, the emulator can be run in background by appending the ampersand:

```
emulator -avd NexusSeven &
```

To ignore all output, the following command will help:

```
emulator -avd NexusSeven > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, really appreciate it. Now maybe you can help me with the extended question, See UPDATE section

Comment: Updated. Just sending stdout and errout to `/dev/null`